# Javascript : ""Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined"" in canvasjs.min.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to get a bar chart from my JSON using javascript but receiving below error message :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined
at q._processMultiseriesPlotUnit (canvasjs.min.js:200)
at q._processData (canvasjs.min.js:197)
at q.render (canvasjs.min.js:181)
at XMLHttpRequest.xhttp.onreadystatechange (Dashboard.js:36)
```

Below is my javascript and JSON:

```
function orderchart(){  
xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("GET", "/getOrderDetails", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.send();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if ((xhttp.readyState == 4) && (xhttp.status == 200)) {
   var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
     var ordercount=jsonResponse.map(function(e) {
           return e.ordercount;
        });
     var season=jsonResponse.map(function(e) {
       return e.season;
    });
     console.log(ordercount,season);
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
        animationEnabled: true,
        theme: "light2", // "light1", "light2", "dark1", "dark2"

        axisX:{
            interval: 1
        },
        axisY2:{                
            title: "Total Orders"
        },
        data: [{
            type: "bar",
            axisYType: "secondary",
            dataPoints:{ y: ordercount, label:season },
        }]
    });
    chart.render();
   }
 }      
 }
```

JSON:

```
[
{
    "season": "Thanksgiving",
    "ordercount": "15000"
},
{
    "season": "Christmas",
    "ordercount": "300000"
},
{
    "season": "Newyear",
    "ordercount": "100000"
}
]
```

My expected bar chart is :

[image: Bar chart]

I am getting this chart when I am manually passing values for datapoints but getting errors when trying to process it from JSON data.

---

I have noticed dumb error in my code which is a missing square parentheses in the datapoints. I have corrected that one like below,

```
     data: [{
            type: "bar",
            axisYType: "secondary",
            dataPoints:[{ y: ordercount, label:season },]
        }]
```

But still not getting the expected graph,

[image: chart]

Comment: Perhaps it is looking for x here? `dataPoints:{ y: ordercount, label:season },`

Comment: Why the `chart.js` tag when it is CanvasJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and you will get result:

```
window.onload = function () {

            var data =  [
                        {
                            "season": "Thanksgiving",
                            "ordercount": "15000"
                        },
                        {
                            "season": "Christmas",
                            "ordercount": "300000"
                        },
                        {
                            "season": "Newyear",
                            "ordercount": "100000"
                        }
                ]

var seasondata = []
for (let index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
    const element = data[index];
    seasondata.push({label: data[index]["season"], y:Number(data[index]["ordercount"])})

}

    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
        title:{
            text: "My First Chart in CanvasJS"              
        },
        data: [              
        {
            // Change type to "doughnut", "line", "splineArea", etc.



            type: "bar",
            dataPoints: seasondata
        }
        ]
    });
    chart.render();

}
```

Put your json data into variable and then create and array and then place that into datapoints Your order count is string so convert that into number and it will work.

You can also check the result here in this link:

[Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/nilayy1234/QwZuf/1935/)